# REST api for processing parallel HTTP GET requests

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, parallel-processing

My question might be quite basic.

I have a Spring MVC (Spring Boot) REST api, and multiple Spark workers that send parallel `HTTP GET` requests to this REST api (e.g. 4 workers on different nodes -> 4 parallel `HTTP` requests). I want my REST api be able to process these requests in parallel.

How can I do it? Should I use callbacks and `DeferredResult` inside my REST api? Any example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`AsyncRestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html).

Answer (score 0):

AsyncRestTemplate is deprecated. Take a look at [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) instead.

Comment: hi, please can you provide context around the link in case it ever breaks? thank you!